# Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined

Tags: phaser-framework

```
function dieCrushed() {
    console.log('crused');
    var txt = this.add.text(x, y, 'GAME OVER');
}
```

ERROR: Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined

I want to write a text to the screen when an I fire this function in phaser3

Answer (score 0):

```js
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    parent: 'phaser-example',
    loader: {
      baseURL: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nazimboudeffa/assets/master/',
      crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
    },
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    physics: {
      default: 'arcade'
  },
  scene: {
    preload: preload,
    create: create
  }
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

function preload()
{
  this.load.image('dude', 'sprites/phaser-dude.png')
}

function create ()
{
  var txt = this.add.text(50, 50, '');
  
  this.input.on('pointerdown', function(){
    txt.setText('GAME OVER')
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.17.0/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```